# New m17n input method does not show up

Tags: ibus, language-support, input-language

When I save https://github.com/sanskrit-coders/m17n-db/blob/master/MIM/kn-optitransv2.mim as /usr/share/m17n/kn-optitransv2.mim , give global read permissions and restart the computer, I am not shown this newly added input method at all in the "Text Entry" settings window:
[image: Screenshot]

How can I get this working?

I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Worked for me, i.e. the "Kannada (optitransv2 (m17n))" option available. You didn't literally save the link you posted, did you? I mean, that's an HTML page. I downloaded [the raw file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sanskrit-coders/m17n-db/master/MIM/kn-optitransv2.mim).

Comment: Hmm - thanks for checking. I did use the raw file (which I wrote and tested myself).

Answer (score 2):

I was able to add the input method once I killed all of these highlighted processes:
[image]

I don't know why restarting the computer did not work, but this did!

Comment: Odd. Restarting (or just relogin) should have been sufficient. Anyway, good that you succeeded in making it work.

Comment: The same trick did not work in a separate computer. Must try restarting.